# Is caulk completed sealed?

Tags: sealant

I bought The following caulk from Home Depot, and I loosely sealed it in a bag, kept it as new. However, when I open the bag today, the chemical fumes blow into my face and I can smell it very strongly.

I have been putting this caulk in my house for a while, and I really worry that the fumes might get all over my house gradually. I'm concerned about the health of my babies.

Do I have anything to worry about?

[image: tube of DAP Alex Plus caulk]
<sup>click to embiggen</sup>

Comment: Look around your house to see how much caulk was there _before_ you moved in. The amount of fume smell when you bought the house is exactly how much you need to worry about it now. Hint: none.

Answer (score 2):

The fumes are much more concentrated in the bag than they are when it's used normally.

Babies are people and people survive occasional exposure to most chewmicals with no lasting ill effects. People used to smoke cigarettes around babies and most of them turned out ok, A little stinky sealant that only pongs for a day or a week or so is no big deal.